# Como reutilizar uma conexão do Mongodb usando Golang?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb, golang

Boa noite a todos..

Tenho um pequeno projeto api em Go com Gin framework, estou usando o mongodb como banco de dados
com o driver `"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"`

Gostaria de abrir a conexão ao iniciar o app, e reusa-la posteriormente em outros packages do app, afim de que não seja criada uma nova a cada requisição. Fiz uma pesquisa e montei o seguinte código:

```
package config

import (
    "context"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "time"
)

var DB *mongo.Database

func init() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    db, _ := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    DB = db.Database("bancoUnico")
}
```

Dessa forma, estou usando a variável `DB` no package de repositório para persistir os dados. Aparentemente, tudo funcionando... Ex:

```
    rep := repositorios.NovoRepUser(config.DB)
    usuario, err := rep.CadastrarUsuario(context.Background(), request)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return usuario, err
```

Devido a pouca experiência, não sei se essa seria a abordagem correta. Se possível, gostaria de orientação para corrigir/melhorar a forma de reusar a conexão com o banco de dados.

Fico agradecido.

Comment: a gente usa aqui um padrão bem parecido com esse config seu, porém os repositórios ficavam como variável ali no config tb.. daí pra usar os repositorios era só fazer `config.UserDao.FindAll()` em qualquer lugar no código

Comment: Muito obrigado Eduardo!!!

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução interessante para o seu problema é Dependency Injection.

**Um exemplo prático:**

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"
)

func OpenDB() (*sql.DB, error) {
    panic("not implemented")
}

type UserRepository struct {
    db *sql.DB
}

func NewUserRepository(db *sql.DB) *UserRepository {
    return &UserRepository{db: db}
}

func (r *UserRepository) Create(u *User) error {
    r.db.Exec("INSERT INTO users (name) values (?)", u.Name)
    panic("not implemented")
}

type User struct {
    ID   uint64
    Name string
}

func main() {
    db, err := OpenDB()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("connect database error", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    userRepository := NewUserRepository(db)

    if err = userRepository.Create(&User{
        ID:   42,
        Name: "Don't Panic",
    }); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("create user", err)
    }
}
```

Com esse código é fácil acompanhar o fluxo de execução, pois evitamos o uso do `init`.

**Seguindo a mesma lógica pode criar handlers/controllers:**

```golang
package controller

func NewUserController(repository *UserRepository) *UserController {
    return &UserController{repository: repository}
}

func (c *UserController) Create(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c.repository.Create(...)
    panic("not implemented")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Creio que isso não seja uma questão da linguagem em específico e sim algo relacionado a arquitetura do seu projeto, existem vários tipos no mercado como clean, ddd, hexagonal etc, decidir qual usar vai variar de acordo com o escopo do projeto, porém se é algo simples você pode usar o SOLID por exemplo, crie uma implementação do seu banco de dados e o injete para seus controllers ou repositórios (ou seja la onde for usar) via injeção de dependência, recomendo estudar bem a orientação a composição do Go e como implementar as interfaces corretamente para aplicar o SOLID.

[Esse artigo](https://alistair.cockburn.us/hexagonal-architecture/) fala sobre a arquitetura hexagonal e o conceito de portas e adaptadores que você pode usar para implementar no seu projeto, e [esse artigo](https://dev.to/ansu/solid-principles-explained-with-golang-examples-5eh) fala de SOLID em Go, arquitetura não é algo que se aprende da noite pro dia mas a longo prazo vai lhe ajudar bastante.